# WPF - Need to change characters of a text box only with a specific string

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm attempting to create a tool for supporting users on my network, basically I have a textbox that you would enter a hostname to. I'm wondering if there is a way to append a character to the text box only when a 6 digit number is entered in the box. If it's anything else, leave it alone.

Basically if the number is 123456 then put a "C" at the beginning "C123456"
but if someone already put the C in - don't do anything.

Also there would be other characters (for other hostnames) that I would not want changed. Only if 6 digits are entered, to put a "c" in front.

Sample code:

This is what i have so far:

```
        private void IPfind(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
                string text = tb.Text.ToUpper();
                int num;
                if (int.TryParse(text, out num))
                {
                    // it is an integer. Simply add a C at the begining if it has enough characters

                    if (text.Length == 6)
                    {
                        tb.Text = 'C' + text;
                        tb.CaretIndex = tb.Text.Length;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    Ipbox.Clear();
                    try
                    {
                        // Host Name resolution to IP
                        IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Assetbox.Text.Trim());
                        IPAddress[] ipaddr = host.AddressList;
                        // Loop through the IP Address array and add the IP address
                        foreach (IPAddress addr in ipaddr)
                        {
                            // Finds the IP V4 address
                            if (addr.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                                Ipbox.Text = (addr.ToString());
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: that can be easily done, just so I give you a good solution could you clarify, you want them to enter into a text box "CXXXXXX" where X is a digit, and if that is correct, you store the letter in front or the whole string in another variable?

Comment: Yes - but the problem is... the 6 digits represent an inventory number, the "C" represents a computer and "P" for printers... both have 6 digits in them... so if someone were to enter the CXXXXXX or PXXXXXX i dont want it to add another C in front of the 6 digits to preserve the hostname. I hope i'm more clear, if not i'll try again. and thanks for help :)

** we also have other hostnames for mainframe networking... such as KICX1234 that also need to be left alone.

Comment: What did you try before asking this question ? Show us your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if` blocks to check everything. I explain different parts in comments:

```
    bool _changing = false; // since you are going to change Text you need this to stop a loop or other errors
    private void Tb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_changing)
            return;
        _changing = true;
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        string text = tb.Text.ToUpper();

        if (text == null || text.Length == 0)
        {
            // The user has not enter enough characters yet
            return;
        } 

        int num;
        if (int.TryParse(text, out num))
        {
            // it is an integer. Simply add a C at the begining if it has enough characters
            if (text.Length == 6)
            {
                tb.Text = 'C' + text;
                tb.CaretIndex = tb.Text.Length;
            }
            else
            {
                // let use to continue typing
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // it is not an integer
            //check if it starts with P or C
            if (text[0] == 'C' || text[0] == 'P')
            {
                string textrest = text.Remove(0, 1);
                if (textrest.Length == 0)
                {
                    // it is just a C or P
                    return;
                }

                if (int.TryParse(textrest, out num))
                {
                    // it became an integer after removing the first char. It is OK then.
                }
                else
                {
                    // it is not a number and removing the first C or P did not solve the problem
                    // throw new FormatException();
                    // or
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Format. Enter ###### or C###### or P#######");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // it is not a number and the reason is not because it starts with C or P
                // throw new FormatException();
                // or
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong Format. Enter ###### or C###### or P#######");
            }
        }
        _changing = false;
    }
```

Comment: This half works for me thanks a lot, the only issue is that it only accepts numbers - because it's an integer... the else statement accepts the input if it starts with P or C... basically i need it to be anything. If i type www.google.ca it would run without changing. The only exception is if it were completely numerical and 6 digits to add a C before it.

Comment: I updated the original post with the code (what i have so far)

Answer (score 0):

So I think Regex could be really useful here,

make your textbox then make a textchanged event like so in the XAMl,

```
 <TextBox x:Name="textBox" TextChanged="textBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Then in C#(code behind), you can add the code to the event,

```
 private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pattern = new Regex(@"(\w[0-9]{6})"); //This is a regex pattern, you can make it much more intelligent, like if you just want P or C chars to accepted rather than any letter
        var isThereMatch = pattern.Match(textBox.Text); // Is there a match?
        string strThingIwannaSAVE = isThereMatch.ToString(); //If there is save that string so you can manipulate it
        if (textBox.Text.Length > 6) //only execute the following code if you have enough characted in your box
        { 
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strThingIwannaSAVE)) //if there is no match or its just whitespaces for some reason, empty out your box or display a message or whatever else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong input");
                textBox.Text = String.Empty;
        }
        else 
        {  
          //String is good, add it to a database? do something to it?
        }           
      }
    }
```

***EDIT***

If you want to just match P or C characters plus the numbers, make two regex patterns,

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"(c{1}[0-9]{6})");
var pattern2 = new Regex(@"(p{1}[0-9]{6})");
```

Then check textbox for matches

Answer (score 0):

Thanks huge to both @JohnChris and @Ramin

I used both solutions to fix this

```
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        string text = tb.Text;
        if (Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^\d+$") && text.Length == 6)
            {
                tb.Text = 'C' + text;
                tb.CaretIndex = tb.Text.Length;
            }
```